# Mandatory input cause actionSupport to fail

Tags: visualforce, actionsupport, required-field, actionregion

I want to create records from individual inputs in a table. 
Individual inputs are made of Users or Contacts participating to a given meeting.
A Meeting__c object is the parent of User and Contacts stored in a Participant__c object.
Users and Contacts are distinguished by Record Types: Internal -> Users ; External -> Contacts. 
Users are stored in a Lookup field User__c ; Contacts are stored in a Lookup field Contact__c.
Ths user has the possibility to select the type of participant in a list box (linked to the RecordTypeID field).

**Goal**: render User__c or Contact__c depending on the value of the RecordTypeID selected by the user.

For that, I use an `<apex:actionSupport>` tag to trigger a controller method that handles the Record Type change and sets the Render variable.

**Problem**: I could write a page that works like expected. But as soon as I have a field required on the page, the actionSupport call fails. The Debug log shows "You must enter a value".

**Diagnostic**: in any case, the call goes into the checking of required fields being filled or not before doing anything else.

What I've done:

1. Enter a value in the required field: no error is raised in this case. But I can't require users to input all the required field PRIOR to entering any value in the participants list (5 fields in the final form)
2. Use immediate="true" in actionSupport
3. Use actionFunction instead of actionSupport
4. Surrounding the `<apex:pageBlockTable>` tag with `<apex:actionRegion>`tags

2 caused a different problem. 3 and 4 couldn't resolve the issue.

**My question is:** is there a way to call directly the controller method without triggering the required checking ?

Thank you for you help

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:inputField value="{!Visit.Visit_date__c}" required="false" />
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Participants}" var="u" title="Participants list" id="ParticipantsList">

            <apex:column headerValue="Participant Type" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!u.participant.RecordTypeId}"  >
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onRecordTypeChange}" reRender="ParticipantsList" >
                        <apex:param name="LineIndex" value="{!u.index}" assignTo="{!CurrentRow}" />
                    </apex:actionSupport>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>       

            <apex:column headerValue="Participant" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!u.participant.User__c}" rendered="{!u.isInternal}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!u.participant.Contact__c}" rendered="{!NOT(u.isInternal)}" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Index" >
                <apex:outputText value="{!u.index}" />
            </apex:column>                

            <apex:column headerValue="isInternal" >
                <apex:outputText value="{!u.isInternal}" />
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question, you want to call controller method on selection of RecordType, without entering other mandatory fields.

This can only be solved using `<apex:actionSupport>` inside `<apex:actionRegion>`.

For example

```
<apex:column headerValue="Participant Type">
    <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField value="{!u.participant.RecordTypeId}"  >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!onRecordTypeChange}" reRender="ParticipantsList" >
                <apex:param name="LineIndex" value="{!u.index}" assignTo="{!CurrentRow}" />
            </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:inputField>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:column>
```

Also, if you are making fields as mandatory based on recordtype selection, for example `User__c`, then wrap that field within `<apex:actionRegion>`. Otherwise use of `required="true"` always fire before submitting the page.

For example

```
<apex:column headerValue="Participant" >
    <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:inputField value="{!u.participant.User__c}" rendered="{!u.isInternal}" required="true"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!u.participant.Contact__c}" rendered="{!NOT(u.isInternal)}" required="true"/>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Hi Santanu,

Thank you very much for your advise. It works fine.

Have a nice day

FB

PS: anyway, it looks like that what I want to do is not possible in APEX/Visualforce. I have to find some other way of doing that. Thanks again